# How do I instantiate a covergroup within a class?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to instantiate a covergroup within a class as below. This class has 2 properties and covergroup.
To allocate the memory, I implemented it in the module:

```
random_data_c rd;  
rd_size_cg rd_size_cg_inst;
```

and assigned `new()` into the `rd_size_cg_inst`

```
class random_data_c;
                   
rand logic [7:0] height;
rand logic [7:0] width;

constraint arr_c { 
                  height inside {[0:5]};
                  width inside {[0:5]};
}                  
                   
covergroup rd_size_cg;    
  option.per_instance = 1;
rd_height : coverpoint height {
bins num[] = {[0:255]};   
illegal_bins ig[] = default;
    }              
                   
rd_width : coverpoint width {
bins num[] = {[0:255]};   
illegal_bins ig[] = default;
    }              
endgroup           
                   
endclass           
                   
                   
module test;
random_data_c rd;  
rd_size_cg rd_size_cg_inst;
                   
initial begin      
  rd = new();      
  rd_size_cg_inst =new();
  assert(randomize(rd));
  $display("height:%h", rd.height);
  $display("width:%h", rd.width);
  foreach(rd.arr[i,j]) begin
    $display("arr[%d][%d]=%h", i,j,rd.arr[i][j]);
  end              
end                
                   
endmodule
```

But, I got this error:

> `rd_size_cg_inst` that unrecognized declaration 'rd_size_cg_inst'
> could be an unsupported keyword.

How do I instantiate a covergroup within a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The covergroup is inside a class, which means that it can only be referenced inside the module using the class handle.  The following runs without errors:

```
class random_data_c;

//...

function new;
    rd_size_cg = new();
endfunction
endclass


module test;
random_data_c rd;

initial begin
  rd = new();
  assert(rd.randomize());
  rd.rd_size_cg.sample();
  $display("height:%h", rd.height);
  $display("width:%h", rd.width);
end
endmodule
```

Note that I added the `new` function in the class to construct the covergroup.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 19.4 *Using covergroup in classes*.